# embed dll in html <object>

Tags: javascript, html, dll, object

I've come across some old code

`<object id="foo" classid="/location/bar.dll#ProjectName.ClassName" viewastext></object>`

It doesn't currently work and used to work in older versions of IE. I've never come across embedding a dll in a web page like this. It appears to be a windows .NET application written in C#. This is used on our intranet.

And ClassName is of type `System.Windows.Forms.UserControl`

It also seems I can call the C# methods of the UserControl directly through javascript.

Does anyone have any documentation on how this works and whether its possible to hack it into firefox. Rewriting the windows control as a web application would be a nightmare.

[Edit]

It appears to be some kind of activeX / COM thing where in IE you could just port a windows application directly into a html file. It's supposed to be able to run locally if you set up various correctly. If anyone has an idea of what needs to be set up for this to work, that would be nice.

Microsoft, you should never have allowed people to port Window controls into IE directly, It's a hideous concept.

Comment: One thing to remember is explorer is somewhat tied into internet explorer (and vise-versa)...    Hence one of the reasons why there are always so many exploits when MS releases a new version (or updated version) of their software....    As for porting/hacking into firefox: none that i have heard of...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its hard to say without knowing exactly what it was for...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a7as3z1d(v=vs.90).aspx

May give you some info...